# Incorrect disassemble output (BeaEngine)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, disassembly

I've gone through significant trouble to achieve what I believe to be a correct setup of BeaEngine with visual studio. 
I will sum up the setup process very quickly :
build of with cmake 3.6 x64, sourcefile ->
C:/Users/Ulysse/Documents/beaengine-master
CmakeLogs : 
Configuring done
Generating done
After which I opened the solution within visual studio and compiled in release mode to obtain .lib and .dll files : BeaEngine_stdcall_64.dll and BeaEngine_stdcall_64.lib.
I have included include and lib folders and have added the lib file to the linker->input->additionnal dependencies within my Visual Studio 2015 x64 project. The project is a 32 bit console application.
I am now trying to run an example taken from BeaEngine website, It compiles, it runs but provides no correct output of disassembled instructions, code is here :

```
int main(void)
{
/* ============================= Init datas */
DISASM MyDisasm;
int nfalse = 0, ntrue = 1;
int len, i = 0;
bool Error = nfalse;

/* ============================= Init the Disasm structure (important !)*/
(void)memset(&MyDisasm, 0, sizeof(DISASM));

/* ============================= Init EIP */
int n;
_asm
{
    push eax
    call get_eip
        jmp out1
        get_eip : mov eax, [esp]
        ret
        out1 :
    mov n, eax
        pop eax
}
MyDisasm.EIP = n; //0x401000;

/* ============================= Loop for Disasm */
while ((!Error) && (i<100)) {
    len = Disasm(&MyDisasm);
    if (len != UNKNOWN_OPCODE) {
        puts(MyDisasm.CompleteInstr);
        MyDisasm.EIP = MyDisasm.EIP + len;
        cout << i << endl;
        cout << MyDisasm.CompleteInstr << endl;
        std::printf("%c", MyDisasm.CompleteInstr);
        i++;
    }
    else {
        Error = true;
    }
};
Sleep(100000);
return 0;
}
```

Note that I've had to add the inline asm part because the example given by BeaEngine's author would crash the program (false EIP as my compiled program never starts at 0x401000). 
Now that I have corrected the EIP the program no longer crashes but puts fonction prints non printable characters and the printf which I have added show always the same character (which isn't ASCII).
Spent the whole day on this, am i missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it took me a whole other day but I found the problem. It's strange that a console win 32 was successfully compiled with the x64 version of the library and that half the program didn't not crash and almost ran perfectly (as it only failed at the last process of the disassembling). I went through the source code of the project and finally i just tried every single cmake build.
The actual problem is that the stdcall option of the cmake gui program wasn't selected. Note that the first few lines of the CMakeLists.txt file are :
project (BeaEngine)
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

## set (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

option (optHAS_OPTIMIZED "Turn Optimizations ON"    OFF)
option (optHAS_SYMBOLS   "Build with debug Symbols" ON)
option (optBUILD_64BIT   "Build 64 bits executable" OFF)
option (optBUILD_DLL     "Build Shared Objects"     OFF)
option (optBUILD_STDCALL "Build using stdcall"      OFF)

However if you get here by trying to get this library working make sure that you use these 2 core options while compiling :
DLL->ON STDCALL -> ON. Then build with msvc and you will good to go.